# JS.Как сделать эффект дрожания при наведение на div

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, ajax

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Цветные прямоугольники </title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link href="css/rect.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="js/rect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="rectanglearea"></div>

        <div>
            <button id="color">Цвет</button>
            <input id="colortouse" type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

при загрузке страницы в div "rectanglearea" создаются заданное количество прямоугольников (примерно 50 на 50px)

Задание: при наведении курсора на прямоугольник(созданный ранее) этот прямоугольник начинает дрожать, а при уходе перестает.

нужно использовать AJAX и JQuery

Comment: Где они создаются? Я не вижу никаких прямоугольников.

Comment: AJAX и JQuery ... o_O ... зачем? На CSS можно сделать ...

Comment: Прошу прощения,
вот скрин https://skr.sh/s8Mml4rqwuV?a
создаются в рандомных местах

Comment: При наведении , например ,самого верхнего он должен дрожать.

Comment: http://usefulscript.ru/image_shaking.php